# Installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 'classic', no .config directory for users

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, systemd, user

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 'classic' on my Pi 3, and am using the CLI which is a struggle but bearable. I've created a user, and subsequent instructions involve configuring a startup daemon in the ~/.config/systemd directory.

The problem: this version doesn't have such a directory. Nor is there one in the /skel folder.

Is this something that can be added or configured to be added when new users are created? Or, is there an alternate path or work-around used instead? Perhaps I'm missing an update or upgrade?

Comment: Can you link to the instructions you are using?  In many cases where a directory doesn't exist, it's fine for you to create them (empty).

Comment: What is `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 'classic'`? How did you install it? `Ubuntu MATE 16.04` works well on a Pi3, but if you don't want a GUI why use `Ubuntu`? I can't imagine **ANY** possible reason for "configuring a startup daemon" in a HOME directory. Link to any "instructions" you may be following.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you actually don't have `~/.config` directory? It will be hidden in most file managers by default, but you should see it with `ls -a` and be able to go inside by typing its name in the address bar, or typing `cd ~/.config` in a terminal.

Just in case, you may want to check if you have `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` set: that variable allows to use a different location for configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to `mkdir ~/.config` if the directory doesn't exist.